# How to append something NOT in the end of the file nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, append, node-modules, fs

I have fs that append a string to the end of the file

```
fs.appendFile('app.js', 'app.get(' + "'/" + article.file + "'" + ', function(req, res) {res.render(' + "'" + article.file + "'" + ');});',
    function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('Saved!');
  });
```

but I need it to show it not like this

```
// Start Server
var server = app.listen(8080, function(){
    console.log('Server running on port 8080...');
});

// The Append
app.get('/d', function(req, res) {res.render('d');});
```

I need it to show it like This

```
// The Append Before starting of a server
app.get('/d', function(req, res) {res.render('d');});

// Start Server
var server = app.listen(8080, function(){
    console.log('Server running on port 8080...');
});
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to create a dynamic route with the filename. 
I would suggest a fixed route that takes the filename as a parameter.

```
app.get('/d/:filename', function(req, res) {res.render('d'+ req.query.filename);});
```

Now when you make the request, the filename is provided as a query parameter and therefore returned in the response.

```sh
GET /d?filename=testfilename
```

I think this approach will get you the results you're looking for.

More details here
https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/HTTP/clients/how-to-access-query-string-parameters/

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You have to either:

- Read the file into memory, insert your content at the beginning, and write it back out to the file; or
- Write your content to a new file, then copy the content of the old file after it

In general, there is no "insert data at" function in standard low(ish)-level file APIs, because something, somewhere has to copy the data in order to move it, and that's kept explicit.

Comment: How I do the first method?

Comment: @Nikasmusicandgaming - Your best bet here is to do your research (for instance, by reviewing [the `fs` module](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html), [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a question with a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.